# SequelizeDatabaseError Error: Table doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to create tables using Sequelize programitacally but its continuously showing that the table does not exist, even after using {force:true}. Please do have a look at the code below and kindly help.

App.js

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const addCompany = require("./controller/routes/addCompany");
const sqlize = require(".//../data/database/database")
const { Company, company } = require("../src/model/companyData")

const {salesUser, team} = require("../src/model/teamData")
const salesTeam = require("./controller/routes/salesTeam")

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static("views"));

app.use("/company", addCompany.router);
app.use("/team", salesTeam.router)


sqlize
  .sync({ force: true })
  .then(result => {
  // console.log(result);
  app.listen(3000);
  })
  .catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

**MODELS :**
companyData.js

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

const sqlize = require("../../data/database/database")


const company = sqlize.define('Company', {
    // Model attributes are defined here
    cname: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull : false
    },
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey : true
    },
    revenue: {
        type: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
        allowNull : false
    },
    country: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
}
);

class Company {

    constructor(cname, id, revenue, country) {
        
        this.cname = cname
        this.id = id
        this.revenue = revenue
        this.country = country
    }
    
    
    async save() {

        //console.log(this)
        let newCompany = company.build(this);
        await newCompany.save();
        console.log('Saved to the database!');
       
    }
    
    async fetch() {
        
        let companyData = await company.findAll();
        //console.log(companyData)
        //console.log(companyData.every(el => el instanceof company));
        //console.log("All users:", JSON.stringify(companyData));
        let cData = JSON.stringify(companyData, null, 2)
        //console.log("CDATA +++++++++",JSON.parse(cData))
        let fetchData = []
        cData = JSON.parse(cData)
        cData.forEach(el => 
        fetchData.push({
            'cname': el.cname,
            'id': el.id,
            'revenue': el.revenue,
            'country': el.country
        }))
        //console.log(fetchData)
        return fetchData
    }

    async delete(id) {
        
        await company.destroy({ where: { id: id } });
    }

    async edit(newData) {
        let oldID = newData.oldID
        const entry = await company.findByPk(oldID);
        if (entry === null) {
        console.log('Not found!');
        } else {
        
            console.log(entry instanceof company); // true
            console.log(entry.dataValues)
            let oldID = newData.oldID
            delete newData.oldID
            console.log(newData)
            
            await company.update(
                
                   newData,
                
                {
                    where: {id: oldID}
                }
            );
            
            await this.fetch()
        }
        
    }

}


module.exports = {
    Company: Company,
    company: company
}
```

**MODELS**
teamData.js

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

const sqlize = require("../../data/database/database")

const team = sqlize.define('salesTeam', {
    // Model attributes are defined here
    empName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull : false
    },
    empID: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey : true
    }
}
);




class salesUser {

    constructor(empName, empID) {
        
        this.empName = empName
        this.empID = empID
    }
    
    
    async save() {

        //console.log(this)
        let newUser = team.build(this);
        await newUser.save();
        console.log('Saved to the database!');
       
    }
    
    async fetch() {
        
       
        try {
            let salesUserData = await team.findAll()
          
            //console.log(companyData)
            //console.log(companyData.every(el => el instanceof company));
            //console.log("All users:", JSON.stringify(companyData));
            let sData = JSON.stringify(salesUserData, null, 2)
            //console.log("CDATA +++++++++",JSON.parse(cData))
            let fetchData = []
            sData = JSON.parse(sData)
            sData.forEach(el =>
                fetchData.push({
                    'empName': el.empName,
                    'empID': el.empID

                }))
            //console.log(fetchData)
            return fetchData
        }
        catch (err) {
            console.error(err)
        }
    }

    async delete(id) {
        
        await company.destroy({ where: { empID: id } });
    }

    async edit(newData) {
        let oldempID = newData.oldempID
        const entry = await company.findByPk(oldempID);
        if (entry === null) {
        console.log('Not found!');
        } else {
        
            console.log(entry instanceof team); // true
            console.log(entry.dataValues)
            let oldempID = newData.oldempID
            delete newData.oldempID
            console.log(newData)
            
            await team.update(
                
                   newData,
                
                {
                    where: {empID: oldempID}
                }
            );
            
            await this.fetch()
        }
        
    }

}

module.exports = {
    salesUser: salesUser,
    team: team
}
```

**DATABASE**
database.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sqlize = new Sequelize('node-database', 'root', 'password', {
  dialect: 'mysql',
  host: 'localhost'
});

module.exports = sqlize;
```

**ERROR I AM FACING :**

..........
Executing (default): SELECT `cname`, `id`, `revenue`, `country`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Companies` AS `Company`;
Executing (default): SELECT `empName`, `empID`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `salesTeams` AS `salesTeam`;
node:internal/process/promises:246
triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
^

```
Error
    at Query.run (D:\Node.js Folder\Test 1\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:52:25)
    at D:\Node.js Folder\Test 1\node_modules\sequelize\lib\sequelize.js:311:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async MySQLQueryInterface.select (D:\Node.js Folder\Test 1\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\query-interface.js:407:12)
    at async Function.findAll (D:\Node.js Folder\Test 1\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1134:21)
    at async Company.fetch (D:\Node.js Folder\Test 1\src\model\companyData.js:63:27) {
  name: 'SequelizeDatabaseError',
  parent: Error: Table 'node-database.companies' doesn't exist
      at Packet.asError (D:\Node.js Folder\Test 1\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:728:17)
      at Query.execute (D:\Node.js Folder\Test 1\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:29:26)
      at Connection.handlePacket (D:\Node.js Folder\Test 1\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:456:32)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (D:\Node.js Folder\Test 1\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:85:12)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (D:\Node.js Folder\Test 1\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\Node.js Folder\Test 1\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:92:25)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
      at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10) {
    code: 'ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE',
    errno: 1146,
    sqlState: '42S02',
    sqlMessage: "Table 'node-database.companies' doesn't exist",
    sql: 'SELECT `cname`, `id`, `revenue`, `country`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Companies` AS `Company`;',
    parameters: undefined
  },
  original: Error: Table 'node-database.companies' doesn't exist
      at Packet.asError (D:\Node.js Folder\Test 1\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packets\packet.js:728:17)
      at Query.execute (D:\Node.js Folder\Test 1\node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:29:26)
      at Connection.handlePacket (D:\Node.js Folder\Test 1\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:456:32)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (D:\Node.js Folder\Test 1\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:85:12)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (D:\Node.js Folder\Test 1\node_modules\mysql2\lib\packet_parser.js:75:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (D:\Node.js Folder\Test 1\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:92:25)
      at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)
      at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
      at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)
      at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10) {
    code: 'ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE',
    errno: 1146,
    sqlState: '42S02',
    sqlMessage: "Table 'node-database.companies' doesn't exist",
    sql: 'SELECT `cname`, `id`, `revenue`, `country`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Companies` AS `Company`;',
    parameters: undefined
  },
  sql: 'SELECT `cname`, `id`, `revenue`, `country`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Companies` AS `Company`;',
  parameters: {}
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: Make sure that `sqlize.models` contains all your registered models right  before calling `sync`

Comment: I am importing all the models before calling sync. Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Anyway, please check how you pass `sqlize` in models and that `sqlize.models` contains `Company`